# How can I create generic type actors - Actor<T> with Message<T> in Akka.Net?

Tags: c#, actor, akka.net, akka-cluster

Is it possible for me to create an actor of Actor<T> type that will take a Message<T> type message as input?

In short, I am trying to something like below.

```
public class SomeActor<T>: ReceiveActor
{
  private readonly ILoggingAdapter log = Context.GetLogger();

  public SomeActor()
  {
    Receive<SomeMessage<T>>(message => {

      log.Info("Received String message: {0}", message);

      //... do something here

    });
    Receive<SomeMessage<T>>(message => {...});
  }
}
```

And, if it is ever valid in akka.net framework, per my understanding, I need to instantiate this actor for every given type T as required. Right?

Answer (score 0):

That syntax is valid - all you need is to create this actor via:

```
var props = Props.Create(() => new SomeActor<int>());
var actor = Sys.ActorOf(props);
```